# How to avoid class inheritance bypass?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have come across a problem which is quite difficult to explain. Consider 3 classes; A, B and C. Following inheritance code is in C# pseudocode:

```
class A 
{
    public int x1 { get; set;}
    public int x2 { get; set;}
}

class B : A
{
     public Property SomeProperty 
     { 
          get 
          {
               return new Property(base.x1, base.x2);
          }
          set
          {
               base.x1 = value.x1;
               base.x2 = value.x2;
          }
     }
}

class C : B
{
     public Property SomeProperty 
     {
         get 
         {
             return base.SomeProperty;
         }
         set
         {
             base.SomeProperty = new Property(value.x1 * 2, value.x2 * 2);
         }
     }
}
```

Please note that the source code for class A and B **cannot** be changed. 
The module which I am working on contains the declaration and definition of Class C. So if I have to change anything, it has to be changed in Class C.

One of the major problems with the module is that there are more than 200 functions like the following:

```
function (A objOfA)
{
    objOfA.x1 = 2;
    objOfA.x2 = 3;
}

function1()
{
    function(new C());
}
```

The problem that the above function call creates is that anything that has been written in the derived class C is completely bypassed, as the type of objOfA is A. Unfortunately I cannot change these functions as many modules are dependent on these functions.

So is there a way such that even if the type of the object is A, functions of C are the ones being called?

Comment: The functions are in class C??

Comment: No. There are actually in a completely different namespace.

Comment: How about `public Property SomeProperty { get { return new Property(x1 * 2, x2 * 2); } set { x1 = value.x1 / 2; x2 = value.x2 / 2; } }`? This assumes that you can actually get those values out of a `Property`.

Comment: @BartvanNieop That is an interesting way.. I'll see if I can use that logic. Thank you :)

Comment: @Bart van Nieop on second thought. I don't think that will work in my case though. The Property is actually the Size of a control in WinForms. While drawing the control it will refer the Size in Control class (Base class).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So is there a way such that even if the type of the object is A, functions of C are the ones being called?

The way to do that is to make those members `virtual`, and then `override` them in the derived types.  However, they need to be declared as `virtual` in the base class for this to be an option.  There is no way to override a non-virtual member.

Comment: Or if it is possible, using an interface for the parameter.

Comment: @Styxxy The base type can't be modified, meaning it cannot be made to implement an interface.  Also note that using an interface would force virtual dispatch of the method, so an interface may or may not be appropriate here, but the real key is simply having the virtual dispatch.

Comment: @Servy That is not possible. Actually the Classes A and B are Control and Button Classes of WinForms. And SomeProperty is actually the Size property of the Control. So A and B are out of my control. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: You are absolutely right. My comment was intended for the case when the function is only interested to call certain functions (and not what kind of object type it is).

Comment: @Abhinav Like I said.  If the method isn't virtual, you can't override it.  The designer of that type went out of their way to *specifically* prevent you from overriding its behavior (by making the members non-virtual), so that they can rely on it doing what they want it to do, and not some arbitrary overridden behavior.

Comment: would method hiding work here?  public new Property SomeProperty

Comment: @johnny5 He's *already* using member hiding, and no, it doesn't work.  That's the whole point.  Hiding the method doesn't change the behavior when the object is statically typed as its base class, only overriding a virtual method would do that.

Comment: @Servy How about something like this: `function(A obj) { if(obj is C) ((obj as C).SomeProperty = new Property(2,3);) }`

Comment: @Abhinav - How will your override of the Size property differ from the standard Size property in the Control class? What are you proposing to change and why?  I note that the `MinimumSize` and `MaximumSize` properties of the `Control` class are marked as virtual.  Can you work with them?

Comment: @Abhinav At that point you might as well just have the method accept a `C` object in the first place.

Comment: @Servy C is just one derived class. There are almost 50 classes which have been derived.

Comment: @Chris Dunaway I use method hiding to do that. I am trying to implement UI scaling independent of what DPI setting has been set in the OS. So before the size is set I have to multiply it with the scaling factor.